# C# DynamoDB Scan/Query nested property value does not work

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, linq, amazon-dynamodb

I researched a lot. However, I'm not able to find a way to scan/query the nested property.

```
public class Details
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public Details Details { get; set; }
    }

        
        public class Details
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public string ClientName { get; set; }
            public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
            public string CreateDate { get; set; }
        }
```

// Here is my scan condition

```
List<ScanCondition> scanConditions = new List<ScanCondition>
            {
                new ScanCondition
                {
                    PropertyName = "Details.ClientName",
                    Operator = ScanOperator.Equal,
                    Values= new object [] { "CitiFinanace" }
                }
            };
```

// Actual Call

```
await context.ScanAsync<T>(scanConditions, dynamoDBOperationConfig).GetRemainingAsync();
```

ERROR : The property is not in Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation says:

[image: AWS SDK for .NET - ScanCondition Class]
[AWS SDK for .NET - ScanCondition Class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_DynamoDB_DataModel_ScanCondition.htm)

Considering this, just replace:

```
Values = new object [] { "CitiFinanace" }
```

by:

```
Values= new string [] { "CitiFinanace" }
```